# Post knockout.js viewmodel to .Net Core (2.0) MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Overview**:

Currently, I try to create an ASP.NET Core MVC website which gets data from the server on page load. After that, the page uses knockout.js to maintain a viewmodel to update the data sent from the server (in the first step). Finally, there is a button which sends the edited data back to the server (through an AJAX request). But the corresponding value in my server method is always empty.

**Current Approach**:

First, there is my model class.

```
    public class Order
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public int Contingent { get; set; }
        public int MaximumOrder { get; set; }
        public int UserOrderCount { get; set; }

        public Order() { }
        public Order(SnackOffer offer)
        {
            Name = offer.Template.Name;
            TemplateId = offer.Template.SnackTemplateId;
            Price = offer.Price;
        }
    }
```

In my view I use the model class as a List (List) and load the data like this:

```
var model = new viewModel();
    @(Json.Serialize(Model.Offers)).forEach(function (item, index) {
        model.offers.push({
            name: item.name,
            templateId: item.templateId,
            contingent: ko.observable(item.contingent),
            userOrderCount: ko.observable(item.userOrderCount),
            price: item.price,
            maximumOrder: item.maximumOrder
        });
    })
```

The viewModel is defined like this (shortend for readability):

```
function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.offers = ko.observableArray();
}
```

Now after someone hits the mentioned update button I call this javascript function:

```
self.ConfirmOrder = function () {
            var data = ko.toJSON(self.offers);

            $('#overlay').css('display', 'block');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/Snack/ConfirmOrder',
                data: data,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
                }
            });
        }
```

Here you can see that I use the ko.toJSON method to convert the observableArray to a JSON String and use this string as the data argument for the ajax post.

The ConfirmOrder method in the MVC Controller looks like this currently:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void ConfirmOrder(List<OrderSnackViewModel.Order> offers)
    {
        foreach (var item in offers)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(item.Name);
        }            
    }
```

There is no logic yet cause the offers list is created (so not null) but the count of list items is always 0.

In a concret example this is the JSON string I receive from the server while load the view:

[{"name":"Test","templateId":1,"price":1.94,"contingent":4,"maximumOrder":7,"userOrderCount":0},{"name":"Test 1","templateId":2,"price":1.50,"contingent":30,"maximumOrder":7,"userOrderCount":0}]

And this is the string i produce with the ajax call:

[{"name":"Test","templateId":1,"contingent":4,"userOrderCount":0,"price":1.94,"maximumOrder":7},{"name":"Test 1","templateId":2,"contingent":30,"userOrderCount":0,"price":1.5,"maximumOrder":7}]

What have I tried already:

- I have tried to use FromBody in my MVC Controller
- I have tried to prefix the JSON output with the name offer so my controller method can map the JSON string items to the object. (e.g. data = '{ "offers":' + data + '}'; )
- I have tried to rename the Properties of my model to match exactly the JSON names. So I renamed Name to name and Contingent to contingent and so on.
- I have tried to use an array instead of the List in the MVC controller action

Is there a master somewhere which can help me with this problem?
(If you need some more information please do not hesitate to ask)

Comment: try `var data = JSON.stringify({ offers: ko.toJS(self.offers)})`

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the fast response. I have tried it with your suggestion but there is no change in the behaviour.

This is the produced JSON:
{"offers":[{"name":"Test","templateId":1,"contingent":4,"userOrderCount":0,"price":1.94,"maximumOrder":7},{"name":"Test 1","templateId":2,"contingent":30,"userOrderCount":0,"price":1.5,"maximumOrder":7}]}

So you think my problem is a missing reference to the offers name of my parameter correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just saw that you've already tried `FromBody` which should've worked with your code.

Comment: To be sure I have tried now both. I added your line of code **AND** use the [FromBody] Attribute. If I do so the error is at least something else. The error now is that with both changes the offers parameter is not an empty List (with count 0) but NULL so my foreach through an exception.

Comment: No, I meant `[FromBody]` with your existing code

Comment: try to add dataType to your ajax request

Comment: Ohh my god please do not hate me but now it is working. I have tried it with the FromBody as adiga suggested. I was sure I already have tried it but maybe I have forgoten the content-type in this try but now everything works as expected.... @adiga should I write the answer or do you want to write it and I mark your answer as working?

Comment: Did it work with what I suggested? If yes, I'll post an answer. Otherwise, you can post your own answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the input of @adiga I have found the solutions for (my) error.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ConfirmOrder([FromBody]List<Order> offers)
{        
    _logger.LogInformation("COUNT -> " + offers.Count());
    foreach (var item in offers)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(item.Name);
    }            
}
```

This is the working solution. I thought I already have tried it but maybe I have forgoten the content-type for the ajax post.

```
var data = ko.toJSON(self.offers);

$('#overlay').css('display', 'block');

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/Snack/ConfirmOrder',
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {
        //location.reload(); 
        $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#overlay').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Thanks again for all responses!